# On the convexity/concavity of c-concave functions

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

Given a cost function $c:\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ we say a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is **c-concave** when there exists some $\psi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$, $\psi\not\equiv -\infty$ such that
$$ \phi(x) = \inf_{y\in\mathbb{R}^d} [c(x,y)-\psi(y)]. $$

If the cost function is the usual euclidean metric $c(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}|x-y|^2$ then we know a function $\phi(x)$ is c-concave iff
$$ \frac{x^2}{2}-\phi(x) \quad \text{is convex.} $$

I was wondering whether there was some way to characterize the convexity/concavity of a c-concave function regarding the concavity/convexity of the cost. In particular I am specially interested in the case in which $c(x-y)$ is a concave function (and a distance indeed).

Thanks in advance!